# Converting chef upstart template to systemd

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, systemd, upstart, chef-template

I have one upstart template in chef-Cookbook and want to convert it into Systemd so that it can be supported in 16.04.
I have already converted but faced the issue as my server is not starting properly.

Below is the upstart script -

```
#!upstart
description "Server nodejs"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE!=lo)
stop on [!12345]

console log

setuid root
setgid www-data
chdir /srv/
exec /usr/local/bin/node /srv/my_service/src/cli/index.js >>/var/log/my_service/my_service_nodejs.log 2>&1
```

Conversion of same in Systemd is -

```
[Unit]
Description=Server nodejs
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/srv/
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node /srv/my_service/src/cli/index.js >>/var/log/my_service/my_service_nodejs.log 2>&1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Issues I am facing -**

- Node js Server is not Running
- my_nodejs.service - Server nodejs
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/my_nodejs.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-12-28 08:01:14 UTC; 6s ago
  Main PID: 5842 (code=exited, status=64)
- systemd[1]: my_nodejs.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=64/n/a

  systemd[1]: my_nodejs.service: Unit entered failed state.

  systemd[1]: my_nodejs.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. 
It is because of the >> which I added for appending log. >> is considered an Operator in Systemd